# UIWebView Cookies

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have an iOS 5.x application that I has a web login that is passing cookies back to save the session information. When the app runs for the first time and use the web login everything works fine, then when I restart the application everything is fine all the required cookies are there the second time I restart the application everything is fine after the third or fourth time the cookies that had been saved seem to have magically disappeared.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Is this over a short period of time or a long period of time.  If over a longish period of time check that its not simply a case of the cookies expiring.  (i.e. is the server setting them as session cookies and the session expiring clearing the cookies?).

Comment: this is over the corse of about 30 seconds the cookies aren't set to expire for at least a year.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be stored in NSUserDefaults as dictionary, and restored whenever the application launches.

Cookies have expire date and max-age, probably that causes the cookies to disappear.